# Prolog: uncaught exception: error(syntax_error('user_input:4 (char:7)

Tags: functional-programming, prolog, logic

I get the following error message when I try to run my Prolog code. I am very new to this language and am having a lot of trouble finding my error. I am using the GNU Prolog compiler.(Version 1.4.4 by Daniel Diaz) I believe the error has something to do with the list or the member predicate. Can you please help me?

```
uncaught exception: error(syntax_error('user_input:4 (char:7) expression expected'),read_term/3)
```

Here is my prolog code.

```
alien(flubsub).
alien(gribbet).
alien(jarix).
alien(wattin).

child(andrew).
child(dudley).
child(georgina).
child(karen).

features(bubbles).
features(colors).
features(eyes).
features(fins).

solve :-
    alien(andrewAlien), alien(dudleyAlien), alien(georginaAlien),alien(karenAlien),

    all_different([andrewAlien, dudleyAlien, georginaAlien, karenAlien]), 

    feature(andrewFeature), feature(dudleyFeature), feature(georginaFeature), feature(karenFeature),

    all_different([andrewFeature, dudleyFeature,georginaFeature,karenFeature]),

    Owners = [ [andrew,andrewAlien,andrewFeature],
        [dudley,dudleyAlien,dudleyFeature],
        [georgina,georginaAlien,georginaFeature],
        [karen,karenAlien,karenFeature]
                     ],

    % 1. Dudley didn't walk out of the store with either Flubsub or Jarix, and his alien doesn't develop fins when placed in water. 
    \+ member([dudley,flubsub,_],Owners),
    \+ member([dudley,jarix,_],Owners),
    \+ member([dudley,_,fins],Owners),


    %2. Jarix (which isn't the name of the alien Andrew picked) has eyes that glow in the dark.

    \+ member([andrew,jarix,eyes],Owners),
     member([_,jarix,eyes],Owners),

    %3 Karen left the toy store with the alien Wattin
    member([karen,wattin,_],Owners),


    %4 Andrew doesn't own the alien that develops fins and Dudley doesn't own the alien that blows bubbles

    \+ member([andrew,_,fins],Owners),
    \+ member([dudley,_,bubbles],Owners),

    tell(andrew,andrewAlien,andrewFeature),
    tell(dudley,dudleyAlien,dudleyFeature),
    tell(georgina,georginaAlien,georginaFeature),
    tell(karen,karenAlien,karenFeature).


    %Succeeds if all elements of the argument list are bound and different
    %Fails if any elements are unbound or equal to some other element

    all_different([H |  T]) :- member(H, T), !, fail.
    all_different([_  |  T]) :- all_different(T).
    all_different([_]).

    tell(x, y, z) :-
        write('  '), write(x), write( ' got the '), write(y),
        write(' with feature '), write(z), write('.'),nl.
```

Comment: Do you mean *compile* or *run*? From what I can tell, Prolog loads your program without generating an error. I tried querying `solve` and it simply failed with no error message.

Comment: I meant 'run'. sorry about that.

Comment: I ran it and it just said "false". No error message. Are you sure the code you show above is the code you ran?

Comment: Yes, it is. I got the same 'false' error message when i used the SWI- prolog compiler. When I switched to GNU-Prolog, I got the more verbose error message which I listed above.

Comment: I tried it on GNU Prolog and got the same results that I got using SWI Prolog.  Querying `solve` gave me "no" (equivalent of "fail"), but no error message. I used `gprolog` version 1.4.4.

Comment: Ok. I was using 'solve();' to run the program. That was probaby a mistake on my part.  I  tried 'solve' and got 'no' and no error message. Do you have any idea of where my logic is wrong?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145322/discussion-between-avi-and-lurker).

Comment: Prolog isn't like Pascal or C. You aren't supposed to use parentheses for no arguments.  I'm pretty sure it fails because of the very first query inside of `solve`: `alien(andrewAlien)`. You don't have a fact or a rule that would make this succeed. You are aware that variables in Prolog must begin with a capital letter or `_` for anonymous variables? See the introductory material in the Prolog documentation.